# jQuery - Is there a way to notify a jquery dialog of an ajax submit action?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a design pattern to handle notifications between a modal dialog and the page that called it.

Say I have a simple Html page that contains one button, which when clicked, loads some content
via ajax into a modal dialog (e.g. jQuery UI dialog). The ajax content that is loaded contains
a simple form with a submit button and this performs an ajax post. So far, so good, and all of 
this works fine.

My question after I have performed by post how do I:
(1) notify the dialog that it can close ? e.g. if I have a method called 'OnSuccess' 
do I go $(??).dialog().close() and 
(2) notify the original page that the dialog closed after a successful post so it can take
an action e.g. rebind a dropdown.

[image: Graphic illustration of events]

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $.ajax success handler to close the dialog.  Then handle the dialog.close event, telling the web page to rebind.  Something like this:

```
// Handler to open dialog
$("#AddItem").click(function() {

    // Show dialog
    $("#DialogElement").dialog({
         close: function() { 
             // code to rebind the drop down
        },
        buttons: {
             SaveItem: function() {
                 // Code to save item to db

                 $(this).dialog("destroy");
                 // Or you can put code to rebind drop down here too
             }
        }
    });

});
```